# Change items ordered informations

Tags: admin, review, page

I'm trying to add an already created custom attribute to the admin order review page. So far I managed to find this function but I don't know what should I change in order to display my attribute, instead of SKU.

```
public function getItemsHtml()
{
    return $this->getChildHtml('order_items');
}
```

[image]

What I have and what I'm trying to accomplish[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Managed to display that attribute using this:

```
<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getarticleNumber()) ?>
```

in `adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/item/column/name.phtml`.